# inserting an image in the database with a BLOB datatype

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0

entity:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "logo")
private byte[] logo;
```

form:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <p:messages showDetail="true"/>  

    <p:fileUpload value="#{testController.file}" 
                  update="messages"  
                  mode="simple"
                  sizeLimit="1048576"   
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>  

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>  

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"  
                     actionListener="#{testController.upload}"/>  
</h:form>
```

bean:

```
private testEntity current;
private UploadedFile file;

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void upload() {
    if (file != null) {
        try {
            byte[] data = file.getContents();
            current.setLogo(data);

            getFacade().edit(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Successful! " + file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

when i try to upload files like 80kb picture, it will give me this exception

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'logo' at row 1
```

but if i upload a mere < 10kb pictures, the code works.

using JSF 2.0, Primefaces 3.5, most codes are auto generated using CRUD.

Comment: How do you declare your database column?

Comment: This is a JPA problem, not JSF.

Comment: i declared it as BLOB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your database column is set to stored less than what you are trying to store. That's what truncating means.

You will need to change your database column definition to LONGBLOB.

Comment: but i was just uploading an 84kb size image

Comment: You may want to [MySQL storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html#id899830).